# Express the sum of the series in terms of elementary functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I have this series and im suppose to express the sum and i think im suppose to use the sum of $e^x$ but im not sure how to figure it out. It would be amazong if someone knows something about how to express this sum. This is the thing I have

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you meant "$\infty$" instead of "$n$".

Denote $$S(x) = \sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}.$$
Now $$e^x= \sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{k}}{k!} = 1 + x + \sum \limits_{k=2}^\infty \frac{x^{k}}{k!} = 1+x+S(x). $$